# Probability that two circles in space are linked

Tags: probability, geometry, 3d, knot-theory

Let $C_0$ be a circle centered on the origin, and $C_1$ a circle centered 
on $(1,0,0)$, center distance of $1$.

> **Q1**. If both $C_0$ and $C_1$ 
>   are randomly oriented and have the same radius
>   $r > \frac{1}{2}$, what is the probability $P(r)$ that the circles are linked?

---

[image: RandCircs2]

---

This is in some sense a straighforward question.
Although "straighforward," I am not finding it an easy computation.
(I would like an exact expression, although numerical approximations are welcomed.)

It may help to start with a simpler question:

> **Q2**. Assume $C_0$ is fixed in the $xy$-plane, and only $C_1$'s orientation
>   is random. What is the probability $P'(r)$ that the circles are linked?

The orientation of $C_1$ is determined by a unit normal vector $\hat{n}$
whose tip is on a unit sphere $S$.
The challenge in Q2 is to work out the region $R$ on $S$ that leads to linking.
The probability $P'(r)$ is then the area of $R$ divided by $4 \pi$.

Even Q2 seems tricky.
If anyone can see considerations that simplify the calculations,
I would appreciate hearing of them—Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For **Q2**, the probability should be just:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\arccos\frac{1}{2r}.$$
Consider the plane $\pi$ where $C_0$ lies. $C_1$ intersect such a plane in two antipodal points $P_1,P_2$ with respect to $(1,0,0)$. If a point between $P_1$ and $P_2$ lies inside the disk that $C_0$ cuts on $\pi$ the two circles are linked, otherwise they are not. But the distribution of the antipodal points  $P_1,P_2$ is uniform on a circle that lies on $\pi$, with center $(1,0,0)$ and radius $r$. Hence we just need to compute the amplitude of the angle depicted in the following figure:

[image: Intersecting circles]

and divide it by $\pi$ to get our answer.
For **Q1**, consider $C_0$ as a fixed circle lying in the plane $\pi$ and let $\Gamma$ be the intersection between $\pi$ and the sphere $S$ concentric with $C_1$ having radius $r$. Let $\pi_1$ be a plane parallel to $\pi$ through the center of $S$. $C_1$ intersects $\Gamma$ only if the angle $\theta$ between $\pi_1$ and the plane containing $C_1$ is big enough. In such a case, $C_0$ and $C_1$ are linked only if $C_1$ intersects $\Gamma$ in a point that lies inside $C_0$. In this case, our probability depends on two (Euler) angles $(\theta,\phi)$ that are uniformly distributed over $[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$.

Given that $d$ is the distance of the center of $S$ from the plane $\pi$ where $C_0$ lies, then $\sqrt{1-d^2}$ is the distance between the center of $C_0$ and the center of $\Gamma$, while $\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$ is the radius of $\Gamma$. The probability depending on the azimutal angle $\theta$ is $\frac{2}{\pi}\arccos\frac{d}{r}$, while the probability depending on $\phi$ can be found by resolving a triangle with side lengths $(r,\sqrt{r^2-d^2},\sqrt{1-d^2})$ through the Cosine theorem. Putting all together, the final probability is:

$$\frac{4}{\pi^2}\cdot\left(\arccos\frac{d}{r}\right)\cdot\left(\arccos\frac{1-2d^2}{2\sqrt{(r^2-d^2)(1-d^2)}}\right).$$

Comment: Brilliant to focus on the antipodal points! Your formula predicts the probability of linking approaches $1$ for large $r$, which makes sense. I gather you are answering Q2 rather than Q1, as in general $(1,0,0)$ does not lie on the plane $\pi$ containing $C_0$...?

Comment: The non-coplanar case is harder to approach since it depends on two angles rather than only one, but the problem becomes affordable if we choice them in order that they are independent. By this way, we almost reduce Q1 to Q2.